# Fire an event for a dynamically created control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make an alert box show the name of the control that triggered an event. In this case, I have a button at the bottom of my page (i_am_the_buttons_name) then when I click it, I want it to show an alert that says its name. This works fine. The problem is, after I click the "Plus" button to add a row of textboxes/a button and try to click the dynamically created button, nothing happens. I've attached a picture that shows this. I hope this makes sense.[image]

jQuery:

```
<script>
        $(window).load(function(){
            $(document).ready(function () {

                var counter = 1;

                $("#removeButtonByID").click(function () {
                    alert(this.name);
                });

                $("#addButton").click(function () {
                    $('<div/>',{'id':'TextBoxDiv' + counter}).html(
                      $('<label/>').html( 'Line #' + counter + ' :  ' )
                    )

                    .append($('<input type="text" placeholder="Item Name">').attr({ 'id': 'textbox' + counter, 'name': 'txtItemName' + counter }))
                    .append($('<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>').attr({ 'name': 'btnRemove' + counter, 'id': 'removeButtonByID' }))
                    .append($('<br />'))
                    .appendTo('#TextBoxesGroup')

                    counter++;
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<hr />
<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
    <!-- Dynamically added textboxes here -->
</div>
<hr />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id='addButton'>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="i_am_the_buttons_name" id='removeButtonByID'>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: Creating duplicate `id`s at `'id': 'removeButtonByID' }` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind it like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.removeButtonByID', function() {
  console.log(this.name);
});
```

Because the additional elements are dynamic, you will need to bind the `click` handler to `document` object with the `id` provided as a parameter.

Also, you would be better off using `class` instead of `id` as the identifier. Because IDs are supposed to be unique.

***Snippet:***

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 1;
    $(document).on('click', '.removeButtonByID', function() {
        alert(this.name);
    });
    $("#addButton").click(function () {
        $('<div/>', { 'id': 'TextBoxDiv' + counter })
        .html($('<label/>').html('Line #' + counter + ' :  '))
        .append($('<input type="text" placeholder="Item Name">').attr({ 'id': 'textbox' + counter, 'name': 'txtItemName' + counter }))
        .append($('<button type="button" class="btn btn-default removeButtonByID"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus">-</span></button>').attr({ 'name': 'btnRemove' + counter }))
        .append($('<br />'))
        .appendTo('#TextBoxesGroup');
        counter++;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<hr />
<div id='TextBoxesGroup'></div>
<hr />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id='addButton'>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">+</span>
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default removeButtonByID" name="i_am_the_buttons_name">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus">-</span>
</button>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `.on` Because you might have a dynamically generated elements, you might want to have the same click handler that was previously bound to the same element selector, you then "delegate" the click event using on() with selector argument.

P.S.
Change id in class because id must be unique.

Javascript:

```
<script>
        $(window).load(function(){
            $(document).ready(function () {

                var counter = 1;

                $("body").on("click",'.removeButtonByID'function () {
                    alert(this.name);
                });

                $(".addButton").click(function () {
                    $('<div/>',{'id':'TextBoxDiv' + counter}).html(
                      $('<label/>').html( 'Line #' + counter + ' :  ' )
                    )

                    .append($('<input type="text" placeholder="Item Name">').attr({ 'id': 'textbox' + counter, 'name': 'txtItemName' + counter }))
                    .append($('<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>').attr({ 'name': 'btnRemove' + counter, 'class': 'removeButtonByID' }))
                    .append($('<br />'))
                    .appendTo('#TextBoxesGroup')

                    counter++;
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<hr />
<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
    <!-- Dynamically added textboxes here -->
</div>
<hr />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" class='addButton'>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="i_am_the_buttons_name" class='removeButtonByID'>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Creating duplicate `id`s at `'id': 'removeButtonByID' }` ? Try delegating `click` event to `document` , setting `id` of dynamically created `button` element to `'removeButtonByID' + counter`

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var counter = 1;

    $(document).on("click", "button[id^=removeButtonByID]", function() {
      alert(this.name);
    });

    $("#addButton").click(function() {
      $('<div/>', {
        'id': 'TextBoxDiv' + counter
      }).html(
        $('<label/>').html('Line #' + counter + ' :  ')
      )

      .append($('<input type="text" placeholder="Item Name">').attr({
          'id': 'textbox' + counter,
          'name': 'txtItemName' + counter
        }))
        .append($('<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus">-</span></button>').attr({
          'name': 'btnRemove' + counter,
          'id': 'removeButtonByID-' + counter
        }))
        .append($('<br />'))
        .appendTo('#TextBoxesGroup')

      counter++;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<hr />
<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
  <!-- Dynamically added textboxes here -->
</div>
<hr />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id='addButton'>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">+</span>
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="i_am_the_buttons_name" id='removeButtonByID'>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus">-</span>
</button>
```